# Passing data from Pop-over ViewController UITextfield back to Master ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, ios9

I have an app setup to have a Master root viewController with a Navigation bar that has a "Settings button". When the user taps the settings button, it brings up a 'settingsTableViewController' that is not dynamic, but rather static so i can format the tableviews with settings like style.

in this settings view, i have a UITextField that takes a Person's name.

When the user clicks "Done" in the navigation bar, i want to pass that name back to the Master Root ViewController so i can use it in the title to display the Person's name. (I want to pass the name upon dismissing the view)

I have tried to use segue's but no luck. Here is a bit of what i tried.

**SettingsViewController (pop's over the MasterVC)**

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {



    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
  override viewDidLoad(){
    self.title = "Settings"
}

// MARK: - Navigation
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Trying to pass what was typed in the textfield to the Root ViewController and store this name in a variable of type String called 'name'

    if segue.identifier == "masterView"{

        let masterViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MasterTableViewController
        masterViewController.name = nameTextField.text


        print("Segue was used")
    }

}

}
```

**MasterTableViewController.swift**

```
 class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var name: String!

  // I am trying to then display the name entered in the pop-over view in this root view controller's title

  override viewDidLoad(){
  self.title = name!
  }
 }
```

My question is, what did i do wrong? I have tried to use delegation but i get nil and the data doesn't seem to get passed either way so any leads will greatly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a different kind of segue called Unwind Segue to do that. It doesn't create a new mvc and its used to pass data back to the vc that presented the current one. here is how to do it
First, go to your storyboard and control drag from settingVc to the exit button on top of it (to itself). it will give you 'Selection Segue' and choose IBAction goBack. This means any vc that presented the current one will get to prepare if they implement this method. In other words, you're putting out a protocol and the presenter vc will conform by implementing goBack IBAction. here is how to implement that. In your Mater vc

```
//You must have this function before you do the segue in storyboard 
@IBAction func goBack(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    /* this is optional
    if let stv = segue.sourceViewController as? SettingsTableViewController{
        self.name = stv.nameTextfield?.text
    }
    */
}
```

In your setting vc (current vc)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //make sure you set the id of your segue to "Your Go back Unwind segue". ofc u can name it whatever 
    if segue.identifier == "Your Go back Unwind segue"{
        if let mtvc = segue.destinationViewController as? MasterTableViewController{
            mtvc.name = nameTextField.text
            print("Segue was used")
        }
    }
}
```

and done method should be something like this

```
@IBAction func doneEditing(sender: UIButton) {
    presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: One Problem: I went into my storyboard, clicked on the SettingsVC tableview and controlled dragged as you said (anywhere in the view) to the Exit icon on top of itself (As you said) and nothing happened, I unlinked this settings view from the Master ViewController and as of now its on its own. (MasterVC has a top left button called "Settings" that calls this Settings VC

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say you need to put the IBAction goBack in your master before you can segue to exit button in storyboard

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work when i pushed the 'Settings' button to bring up the modal view to put data in the textfield. When clicked done nothing happened.

Comment: thats because you're sending the dismiss to self but you should call it on presenter vc, I added done func in my answer